# Rudin 9.19 Implicit Function Theorem Exercise

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

> 19. Show that the system of equations
>     $$
>     \begin{array}{r}
>     3 x+y-z+u^{2}=0 \\
>     x-y+2 z+u=0 \\
>     2 x+2 y-3 z+2 u=0
>     \end{array}
>     $$
>     can be solved for $x, y, u$ in terms of $z$; for $x, z, u$ in terms of $y$; for $y, z, u$ in terms of $x$; but not for $x, y, z$ in terms of $u$.

I am trying to show that this system can be solved for $x,y,u$ in terms of $z$. Does this need to have a solution set for every single $z\in\mathbb{R}$? I am thinking about applying the implicit function theorem however this would require checking that the derivative is non-invertible.

If I view this function as $f:\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^3} $

$$f(x,y,z,u)=[3x+y-z+u^2, x-y+2z+u, 2x+2y-3z+2u]$$

I get that the total derivative w.r.t. (x,y,u) is

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 2 u \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{array}\right]$$

Would this need to be invertible for every $u$ for the implicit function theorem to find a function in terms of $z$ that can solve the system of equations?

Comment: @MrProof The right answer marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the last two equations and subtracting the first yields $3u-u^2=0$, then either $u=0$ or $u=3$. Therefore, unless u has one of these values there is no solution. so the system can not be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u$. If one of these two equations holds we can solve just the last two equations for any two of the variables $x,y,z$ in terms of the third one. the remaining equations will be automatically satisfied. For instance

$$x= - \frac z 4 ,\,\,y = \frac{7z}{4},\,\, u=0;\,\, x= - \frac{9+z}{4},\,\, y = \frac{3+7z}{4},\,\, u=3.$$

Also, we could have

$$x= -\frac{y}{7},\,\, z = \frac{4y}{7},\,\,u=0;\,\, x = \frac{60+4y}{7},\,\, z= \frac{4y-3}{7},\,\, u=3.$$

Finally, we also could have

$$y = -7x,\,\, z=-4x,\,\, u=0;\,\, y =\frac{7x-60}{4},\,\, z= 9-4x,\,\, u=3.$$

Note that the matrix of the derivative of the transformation

$$f(x,y,z,u) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3x+y-z+u^2 \\
 x-y+2z+u \\
2x+2y-3z+2u
 \end{pmatrix}$$
is

$$f'(x,y,z,u) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3&1& -1&2u \\
 1&-1&2&1 \\
2&2&-3&2&
 \end{pmatrix}$$

and any $3 \times3$ submatrix containing the least column is invertible when $u=0$ or $u=3$. However, the first three columns of this matrix do not form an invertible matrix.

Comment: Thank you but this seems to be the copy/paste solution from the Rudin solution manual. Would you mind showing how to apply the implicit function theorem here?

Comment: @SamKirkiles You can see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem, the statement of the theorem, in your case $f:\mathbb R ^3 \times \mathbb R ^1 \to \mathbb R ^1$. See that the invertibility of the matrix is not possible for every $u$.